# Angular7 pass new data to child component when parent has action

Tags: angular, parent-child, onchange, reload

Parent contain a child component and a button

Parent contains a string color: `[color]=color`

when clicked on the button,

the data is passed to the child and trigger `ngOnChanges`

parent.html

```html
<button (click)=>'changeColor()'>Change Color </button>
<app-child [color]=color></app-child>
```

parent.ts

```
color = {color: 'blue'}
changeColor(){
  this.color.color = 'red'
}
```

child.ts

```
@Input() public color: string;
ngOnChanges() {
  console.log('onchange')
}
```

child.html

```html
<div>color.color</div>
```

The `ngOnChanges` is not triggered but the html did react to the change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this.color= Object.assign({}, this.color);
will trigger the onchange when passing an object

Answer (score 0):

The logic in the code is good, but the syntax is off:

```html
<button (click)=>'changeColor()' />
<app-child [color]=color></app-child>
```

should be:

```html
<button (click)='changeColor()'>Click me</button>
<app-child [color]='color'></app-child>
```

Notice in the first line I removed the `>` and in the second, I added quotes.
I also added the closing tag in the first line as the text in between tags is the text of the button.

Also, in your child component, the copde is missing the interpolation:

```html
<div>{{color}}</div>
```

Check this page: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax

Comment: thank you for your reply, the problem now is how to pass the changed color to the child, the syntax is wrong when I uploaded.

Comment: This is where you are already passing the color to the child: `[color]='color'`. Angular will pass the updated version each time you change `color`. Do you have an `@Input() color;` in the child component? Could you add that code to the question?

Comment: I have editted the code, please check again , thank you

Comment: You edited it a lot, now the issue is different from before, I'll edit my answer with the issue for the previous version of the code. (Don't modify the fields of the object you are passing, Angular won't see that change, modify the object's reference as you were doing before).